# Finding out the events on a page and what are attached to an element

Tags: jquery-ui, firebug

I'm trying to use firebug to debug some pages. What I want to do is look at what the events are against a particular element. For example : http://jsfiddle.net/2LN5G/, I want to use Firebug and select the "Drag me to my target" and for it to take me to "$( ".drag" ).draggable({" section of the page or the JS file.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This Firefox extension that works with Firebug might be what you need: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug

Comment: Hi Cody, Thanks for your response. But the EventBug takes me to the Jquery file instead of taking it to my declaraiont (i.e $("drag").draggable({..."

Answer (score 0):

maybe using [fireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/%20%22fireQuery) would give you a more precise answer?